# How to hide my Android library dependencies from the client app?

Tags: android, dependencies

My library project has some dependencies on libraries like OkHttp. How do I hide these dependencies from the apps that are going to use my library?

Comment: First, what do you mean by "hide"? Second, why would you want to "hide" them?

Comment: I mean I don't want the apps using my library be able to call new OkHttpClient() for example. Basically, I don't want them to know what libraries I've used to create my own library.

Comment: "I mean I don't want the apps using my library be able to call new OkHttpClient() for example" -- why not? They have as much right to use OkHttp as you do. More importantly, they need to be able to replace the OkHttp being used by their app as needed, such as upgrading to a newer one that fixes security flaws.

Comment: Man, it's so sad when people don't answer questions with answers. He just want to hide the jars he is using. Is that too much of an ask. If not possible, then let him know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, but they can hide them themselves.  The consumers of your library would add this line to their Gradle Build Script.

```
compile('com.blah.yourlibrary:1.0.0') {
    exclude module: 'OkHttpLibraryIdentifier'
}
```